# postgres 8.4: makeslave it's own master

Tags: postgresql, master-slave-replication, postgresql-8.4

For a DR test, I've tried to split the slave from the master.  To do this, I edited the master postgresql.conf, turned off archive_mode and restarted.  No problem.

Now I'm trying to make the slave a master, so I added recovery_target_time to recovery.conf, ensured that archive_mode is off in the postgresql.conf file, and tried to restart.

This failed.  (The command scrolled off the screen, so I can't show the results.)

```
pg_ctl stop -D
```

This worked:

```
pg_ctl stop -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -m immediate
```

So I tried to restart:

```
[postgres@stdrcdsdb202 ~]$ pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -w            
waiting for server to start....
LOG:  could not create IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at log time 2017-08-23 23:22:55 EDT
HINT:  If this has occurred more than once some data might be corrupted and you might need to choose an earlier recovery target.
LOG:  starting archive recovery
LOG:  restore_command = '/usr/bin/pg_standby -l -d -s 2 -t /tmp/pgsql.trigger.5432 /var/lib/pgsql/backups/wal_archives %f %p %r 2>>standby.log'
LOG:  recovery_target_time = '2017-08-23 22:30:00-04'
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
.FATAL:  the database system is starting up
.FATAL:  the database system is starting up
(snip)
.FATAL:  the database system is starting up
.FATAL:  the database system is starting up
.FATAL:  the database system is starting up
.LOG:  restored log file "0000000100003022000000B0" from archive
LOG:  automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  redo starts at 3022/B0D18388, consistency will be reached at 3022/B1000000
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
.FATAL:  the database system is starting up
.FATAL:  the database system is starting up
(snip)
.FATAL:  the database system is starting up
.FATAL:  the database system is starting up
.FATAL:  the database system is starting up
.could not start server
```

But...

```
[postgres@stdrcdsdb202 ~]$ pg_ctl status -D /var/lib/pgsql/data
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 5669)
/usr/bin/postgres "-D" "/var/lib/pgsql/data"

[postgres@stdrcdsdb202 ~]$ psql
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

Any hints or solutions?

Thanks

Comment: When you stopped DR the slaves was in an inconsistent state as can be seen by `LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at log time 2017-08-23 23:22:55 EDT`. I guess you would be best off with a backup on master and a restore on the slave.